# Java CompletionStage to CompletionStage<Either> type is lost

Tags: java, completable-future

Say I have this method:

```
public CompletionStage<SomeClass> getData() {
    CompletableFuture<SomeClass> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        // Fetch data from some source
        // Then either
        // future.complete(data);
        // or fail
        // future.completeExceptionally(e);
    });

    return future;
}
```

And now I want to have a method, that calls `getData`, manipulates, but then returns an `CompletionStage<Either<ErrorResponse, Data>>`

```
public CompletionStage<Either<ErrorResponse, Data>> modifyData() {
    return getData()
       .thenCompose(d -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Either.right(d)))
       .exceptionally(e -> Either.left(ErrorResponse.create(e)));
}
```

When I do this, the type inside the `exceptionally` is lost, and the compiler thinks I am returning a type `Either<Object, Data>`.

If I however change that code to:

```
public CompletionStage<Either<ErrorResponse, Data>> modifyData() {
    CompletableFuture<Either<ErrorResponse, Data>> future = new CompetableFuture<>();

    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        getData()
           .thenCompose(d -> future.complete(Either.right(d)));
           .exceptionally(e -> 
               future.complete(Either.left(ErrorResponse.create(e)))
    });

    return future;
}
```

Then it works fine. Why is the type lost?

Comment: Where are you constructing the `Either.right`-instance in the first `modifyData` function?

Comment: @marstran oops, ya I forgot to add that. It should be in the `CompletableFuture.completedFuture`

Comment: You may get around your problem if you help the compiler a bit by explicitly providing some type parameters. Also, I would use `thenApply` instead of `thenCompose` to avoid the construction of a new `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: I tried `Either<ErrorResponse, Data> either = Either.left(ErrorResponse.create(e))` and then return that `either` in the exception. Now it says `Either<ErrorResponse, Data>` cannot be casted to `Either<Object, Data>`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis so how do I convert a function that returns `CompletionStage<SomeType>` to one that returns a `CompletionStage<OtherType>`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks! If you post, I'll mark as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
public CompletionStage<Either<ErrorResponse, Data>> modifyData() {
    return getData()
       .thenCompose(d -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Either.right(d)))
       .exceptionally(e -> Either.left(ErrorResponse.create(e)));
}
```

[`thenCompose`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenCompose-java.util.function.Function-) is a generic method, but you don't provide enough type information for Java to infer that you want its type parameter `U` to be bound to `Either<ErrorResponse, Data>`. The call to `exceptionally` (even if it was generic) also can't feed back type information to the invocation of `thenCompose`.

Currently, it infers `Object` for `Either`'s first type parameter. So `thenCompose` returns a `CompletionStage<Either<Object, Data>>`. That propagates to `exceptionally`. Since `CompletionStage<Either<Object, Data>>` isn't a `CompletionStage<Either<ErrorResponse, Data>>`, it's an invalid type for a return value.

You can add the necessary type information by providing an explicit type argument.

```
public CompletionStage<Either<ErrorResponse, Data>> modifyData() {
    return getData()
       .<Either<ErrorResponse, Data>>thenCompose(d -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Either.right(d)))
       .exceptionally(e -> Either.left(ErrorResponse.create(e)));
}
```

or closer to the problematic invocation

```
public CompletionStage<Either<ErrorResponse, Data>> modifyData() {
    return getData()
       .thenCompose(d -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Either.<ErrorResponse, Data>right(d)))
       .exceptionally(e -> Either.left(ErrorResponse.create(e)));
}
```

Now Java doesn't have to try and guess. It knows what you meant.

Alternatively, I would use [`CompletableFuture#handle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#handle-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to handle the exceptional case.

```
return getData()
            .handle((d, e) -> {
                if (e == null) {
                    return Either.right(d);
                }
                return Either.left(ErrorResponse.create(e));
            });
}
```

The type information is self-contained. The rest is mostly a matter of opinion.